# create trigger that doesnt let you delete an employee with more tha 10 orders on the Northwind database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, northwind

How to create an SQL trigger that doesnt let you delete an employee that made more than 10 orders on the Northwind database??

I've gotten this far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER emplDel ON Employees AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @num INT
SELECT @num= COUNT(OrderID)
FROM Orders
WHERE EmployeeID= --what id should i use?
if (@num>10)
ROLLBACK
END
```

Comment: @Kritner `AFTER` triggers can `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` to undo work they don't like. I'm not a fan of enabling cascading delete, so I'd bundle all of the functionality in a stored procedure that validates the employee(s) against the business rule and, if there are no problems, delete the order details, headers and employees. It needs to be wrapped in a suitable transaction since there are multiple steps involved.

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that it  will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER empDel ON [Employees]
  INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
  BEGIN
    WITH  orderCounts
            AS (
                 SELECT [EmployeeID],
                        (
                          SELECT  COUNT(*)
                          FROM    [Orders] AS [o]
                          WHERE   [o].[EmployeeID] = [d].[EmployeeID]
                        ) AS OrderCount
                 FROM   [Deleted] AS [d]
               )
      DELETE  FROM [Employees]
      WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT *
                       FROM   [orderCounts] oc
                       WHERE  oc.[EmployeeID] = [Employees].[EmployeeID] AND
                              [oc].[OrderCount] < 10 );

  END;
```

Comment: I'd be more inclined to let the user know that there's an issue rather than silently hide it by only deleting some of the employees rows. Using an `AFTER DELETE` trigger with a `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` and `THROW`/`RaIsError` to report the problem is likely to reduce future head scratching.